# .htaccess e regras de rescrita em servidor PHP

Tags: php, htaccess, mvc

Estou desenvolvendo um microframwork php, e estou utilizando o servidor embutido  do php (php -S 127.0.0.1:8000 -t public) com diretório raiz na pasta public/.

Eu não sei se o .htaccess funciona ou esta funcionando neste servidor.

Ocorre que ao acessar uma rota que não seja raiz ("/") como por exemplo: "/propriedades", o caminho dos arquivos de CSS, imagens e similares estão se sobrepondo a rota, como: "/propriedades/ext/css/...", onde o normal deveria ser: "/ext/css/...".

Acessando a rota "/propriedades" (FUNCIONANDO CORRETAMENTE):

```
[Sat Nov 17 20:35:12 2018] ::1:34630 [200]: /propriedades
[Sat Nov 17 20:35:12 2018] ::1:34634 [200]: /ext/css/core.css
[Sat Nov 17 20:35:12 2018] ::1:34636 [200]: /img/logo02.svg
[Sat Nov 17 20:35:12 2018] ::1:34638 [200]: /img/default-image.png
```

Acessando a rota "/propriedades/" (PROBLEMA):

```
[Sat Nov 17 20:35:10 2018] ::1:34620 [200]: /propriedades/
[Sat Nov 17 20:35:10 2018] ::1:34622 [404]: /propriedades/ext/css/core.css - No such file or directory
[Sat Nov 17 20:35:10 2018] ::1:34626 [404]: /propriedades/ext/js/core.js - No such file or directory
[Sat Nov 17 20:35:11 2018] ::1:34628 [404]: /propriedades/ext/js/core.js - No such file or directory
```

As rotas são captadas e tratadas pela classe de rotas do sistema.
Abaixo segue o arquivo .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Alguém consegue pelo menos me dar alguma ideia do que eu deveria tentar fazer para solucionar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Eu não sei se o .htaccess funciona ou esta funcionando neste servidor.

O servidor interno do php não irá considerar o .htaccess

> Alguem consegue pelo menos me dar alguma ideia do que eu deveria tentar fazer para solucionar?

Independente do .htaccess você precisa corrigir como o seu HTML referencia os arquivos CSS. Provavelmente você está usando links relativos:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ext/css/core.css">
```

Na raiz do site isso funciona bem, mas ao acessar uma outra rota, o navegador envia junto o segmento da url.

Você pode referenciar esse arquivo a partir da raiz, assim ele irá funcionar em qualquer rota:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/ext/css/core.css">
```

É interessante também gerar a URL completa, e no futuro permitir que ela seja configurável para um domínio diferente (ao usar um CDN por exemplo) para ter mais controle:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost/ext/css/core.css">
```

Comment: Problema resolvido seguindo sua resposta!! Muito obrigado amigo!